# invalid arrayify value while using bytes32 array

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, erc-721

Since we cannot pass string arrays as parameters in solidity I used a byte32 array in a function. The code gives no error at compile time. But when I give input to the drawCard function as below in Remix IDE

```
"this is token uri", ["maham",67,"Silver","First Token","image url"]
```

I get the following error:

```
transact to CryptoGogos.drawCard errored: Error encoding arguments: Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value="maham", code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.0.5)
```

My code is as follows:

```
   function drawCard(string memory _tokenURI, bytes32[] memory params) public {
        require(uint(params[1])<total_supply,
        "Input supply is not less than total supply of cards.");
        _tokenIds.increment();
        uint256 newNftTokenId = _tokenIds.current();
        
        Cards memory c;
        c.name = string(abi.encodePacked(params[0]));
        c.supply = uint(params[1]);
        c.cat = string(abi.encodePacked(params[2]));
        c.description = string(abi.encodePacked(params[3]));
        c.image_url= string(abi.encodePacked(params[4]));
        c.card_id = newNftTokenId;
        
        card.push(c);
        tokeninfo[newNftTokenId] = c;
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is that you populate the `params` array with `uint` and `string` arguments whereas it only accepts `bytes32` values.

Basically a `bytes32` is an hexadecimal of length 64 without the 0x prefix (1 byte = 2 hex characters).
To convert something to bytes32, convert it to hexadecimal first, then add as many 0s as needed at the beginning to get a hexadecimal of length 64 (without 0x).

Example with `maham` :

hex -> 6d6168616d

bytes32 -> 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000006d6168616d

Note that the 0x prefix is mandatory with remix so the lenght of each of your bytes32 argument should be equal to 66.

Answer (score 3):

I was giving wrong input to a bytes32 array. The correct way was to convert each value to 0x followed by a 64-character hexadecimal string. Thus "this is token uri", `["maham",67,"Silver","first token","image url"]` became `["0x6d6168616d000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x53696c7665720000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x666972737420746f6b656e000000000000000000000000000000000000000000","0x696d6167652075726c0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000"]`.

Comment: You are correct about the 0x followed by a 64-character hexadecimal string part. However you should add the zeros at the beginning, not the end.

Comment: For exemple 0x4300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 = 30304960855078848021012718732742538383473003799210616369701789564571014397952 in decimals.

Comment: Whereas 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000043 = 67, the value you want.

Comment: You can check my answer to this question for more info.

Answer (score 2):

Most of the time we try to provide a string but it has to be bytes32 in the following format:

```php
// 'ETH' as a bytes32 string
0x4554480000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: Is there a specific function in solidity for generating such a bytes32?